# Cannot open DefaultTest.dll for unit test

Tags: c++

When I try to run my unit test in VS 2012 I get the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Tests, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\Patryk\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LUT\Debug\DefaultTest.dll'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It works again, when I restart VS but then I get the same error after I have to rebuild the project

Comment: Is `DefaultTest` another project in the same solution? Is it set up as a dependency of `Test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this error if the testing engine is still running in background.

Check if the `vstest.executionengine.x86.exe` process is still running in background, and kill it if so. Afterwards you can rebuild and run your tests.

Answer (score 2):

"DefaultTest.dll" is a remnant of not changing the Target Name in the project's General Configuration Properties.

The same thing happens to me in Visual Studio 2010. Removing the .dll and .dll.metagen files from the output directory and rebuilding the test project solved the problem in my case.

Comment: Also changing the field from DefaultTest.dll to "inherit from project defaults" for some strange reason.