# PDB file generated in Release but not Debug mode in VS 2013 Unmanaged C++/CLI

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, c++-cli

I'm trying to debug a tricky problem but I'm finding that my Release mode is getting PDB files but not my Debug mode.  I need the PDBs in Debug mode, natch.

What's going on?

Here's the Release mode compiler options:

```
/GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I".." /I"C:\Users\Kevin\dev\IPCommon\Cpp"   /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "LINKMETHODS_EXPORTS" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\LinkMethods.pch"
```

Here's the Release linker options:

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\Kevin\dev\EXO\x64\Release\LinkMethods.dll" /MANIFEST /LTCG /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\Kevin\dev\EXO\x64\Release\LinkMethods.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "LinkData.lib"  /IMPLIB:"C:\Users\Kevin\dev\EXO\x64\Release\LinkMethods.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"C:\Users\Kevin\dev\EXO\x64\Release\LinkMethods.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Release\LinkMethods.dll.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /VERBOSE /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\Kevin\dev\EXO\x64\Release\" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\UnitTest\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\Kevin\dev\EXO\Dependencies\opencv249\bin" /TLBID:1
```

And here's the Debug mode compiler options:

```
/GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I".." /I"C:\Users\Kevin\dev\IPCommon\Cpp"  /Zi /Gm /Od /Fd"x64\Debug\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "LINKMETHODS_EXPORTS" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\LinkMethods.pch"
```

And Debug Linker options:

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\Kevin\dev\EXO\x64\Debug\LinkMethods.dll" /MANIFEST /LTCG /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\Kevin\dev\EXO\x64\Debug\LinkMethods.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "LinkData.lib"  /IMPLIB:"C:\Users\Kevin\dev\EXO\x64\Debug\LinkMethods.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Users\Kevin\dev\EXO\x64\Debug\LinkMethods.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\LinkMethods.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /VERBOSE /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\Kevin\dev\EXO\x64\Debug\" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\UnitTest\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\Kevin\dev\EXO\Dependencies\opencv249\bin" /TLBID:1
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're missing `MyProjectName.pdb` in the final output directory, not `vc120.pdb` in the intermediate directory. `MyProjectName.pdb` is generated by the linker, not the compiler.

Comment: Side note: You're compiling with Unicode in Debug, but MBCS in Release. You're using precompiled headers in Release but not in Debug. You should probably make those match.

Comment: Thanks @DavidYaw, I've tried your suggestions.  It didn't work, but it was definitely worth a shot.

Comment: And the downvote is because...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Release linker options includes [`/DEBUG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe4t6fc1%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), and the Debug linker options don't.

---

Side notes

There's a few things different between your Debug and Release options that generally aren't different. This may be fine, or it may be that you made the change in one and forgot to make it in the other. Either way, they're probably not related to the problem you're having.

- You're compiling with Unicode in Debug, but MBCS in Release.
- You're using precompiled headers in Release but not in Debug.
- You're specifying `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` in Release, but nothing in Debug. (The default is based on which main method you declare.)

Comment: Argggh!  Thanks!  Adding the /DEBUG switch to Debug still hasn't switched on the PDB compilation.  I've also changed the character set, windows subsystem and the PCH to be the same but the problem is still there. I've added the revised options to the question above, minus the extraneous *.lib  The maddening thing is that it's got to be just a single switch but what that switch is...

Comment: FOUND IT!  The final problem was the missing Gm- "NO minimal rebuild" flag on the Debug compile.  Apparently minimal rebuilds prevent the PDB from being generated.  Thanks for sticking with me!  Add the Gm- option to your answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Another thing that can prevent the generation of PDB files in unit tests is the Target not getting set for some reason. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946087/cannot-open-defaulttest-dll-for-unit-test